# UI5: Bind data dynamically

Tags: sapui5

I have data for UI5 coming in looking like this:

```
"results": [
{
    "ItemType": "AAA",
    "AAA": {
      "Name": "Name of AAA"
     },
    "BBB": null,
    "CCC": null
},
{
    "ItemType": "BBB",
    "BBB": {
      "Name": "Name of BBB"
     },
    "AAA": null,
    "CCC": null
},
{
    "ItemType": "CCC",
    "CCC": {
      "Name": "Name of CCC"
     },
    "AAA": null,
    "BBB": null
}]
```

I want to bind them to a xml view element and get the `Name` field of whatever element I am in. As near as I can tell, I need to do something like this:

```
<Text text="{= ${Data&gt;ItemType} === 'AAA' ? 
    ${Data&gt;AAA/Name} :  
    ${Data&gt;ItemType} === 'BBB' ?
        ${Data&gt;BBB/Name} :
        ${Data&gt;ItemType} === 'CCC'?
            ${Data&gt;CCC/Name} :
            'Unknown Type'}
    "/>
```

This works, but I can't help feeling there is a better way to do the same thing. At the very least, I have to repeat that ugly inline for every similar element.

I tried to do something like this (and many variations thereof):

```
{= Data&gt;${Data&gt;ItemType}/Name}
```

Obviously it didn't work.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no better way. Dynamic databinding is not supported.

An alternative would be to use a factory function for the aggregation binding. that would move most of the ugly stuff to the controller so it's probably not a better solution.

You could however transform your model data to something more suitable for binding right after the data is received.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a formatter function? That would tidy up the code into a single re-usable block. You will still need the 'if' logic but wrapped inside the formatter.